# clientY returns the pixel's Y from the entire screen, not the div

Tags: javascript

I've built a div, which upon click alerts the x and y coordinates of the pixel my cursor is above. This employs clientX and clientY.
However, the y is relative to the screen, and I want it to be relative to the div.

Comment: And you'd like us to guess at the code you wrote that's doing this?

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm only looking for general guidelines in these situations. The script itself is kinda irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to use the offset of the element (div from your description) along with the y position to get the relative y position. The offset will give you the y position of the element itself. Thus subtracting the position from the click location will give you relative (to the div) y location.

`event.clientY - event.target.offsetTop`

You can see a little demo with [Y Position Offset](https://codepen.io/meltingchocolate/pen/EEyxBa) (be sure to open the console so you can see the output - the button is at the bottom left corner of the screen). Otherwise, if your trouble is more specific, it would help to see what you have so far.